# Java regex to distinguish special characters while allowing non english chars

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I am trying to do above. One option is get a set of chars which are special characters and then with some java logic we can accomplish this. But then I have to make sure I include all special chars.

Is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: There are various APIs in `java.lang.Character` like `isLetter(char)` and `isWhitespace(char)`. Can you express what you want to do using those constructs? If so, the conversation about translation into regex would be more efficient.

Comment: So suppose i am validating an input. If we discard non english chars, I can validate special characters from a regex like ([a-zA-Z0-9]). So when the input is with non english characters above logic consider it as a special character as it does not match the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what constitutes a special character. One method that may be of interest is [Character.getType(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28char%29) which returns an int which will match one of the constant values of Character such as Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER or Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL. This lets you determine the general category of a character, and then you need to decide which categories count as 'special' characters and which you will accept as part of text.

Note that Java uses UTF-16 to encode its char and String values, and consequently you may need to deal with supplementary characters (see the link in the description of the getType method). This is a nuisance, but the Character method does offer methods which help you detect this situation and work around it. See the [Character.isSupplementaryCodepoint(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSupplementaryCodePoint%28int%29) and [Character.codepointAt(char[], int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt%28char%5b%5d,%20int%29) methods.

Also be aware that Java 6 is far less knowledgeable about Unicode than is Java 7. The newest version of Java has added far more to its Unicode database, but code running on Java 6 will not recognise some (actually quite a few) exotic codepoints as being part of a Unicode block or general category, so you need to bear this in mind when writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to remove all control characters from a Unicode string. You can accomplish this by using a Unicode character category identifier in a regex. The category "Cc" contains those characters, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[\p{Cc}]+", "");
```

Comment: But when you are given some non english characters it also says false. I want that to be allowed.

Comment: Are you sure you are processing a correct Unicode string? You may have a UTF-8 string incorrectly transformed into bytes/ASCII. This would also cause the Regex to match the UTF-8 control sequence chars (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).